# Jenkins job ssh credentials input

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, credentials

I'm trying to have a jenkins job that will trigger commands and/or bash scripts from the jenkins master to a system that is not connected as a slave or any trust between the two.
All the jenkins plugins I found require that from jenkins configure menu you add first the server and credentials.
This is not ideal as I want the IP and credentials to be entered when the job is executed.

what I could get so far is to simply take in as parameters the IP and username/password, then from the jenkins job execute command to use ssh and the taken variables/credentials.

Are there any plugins to facilitate this better or how do you handle this if the system is not previously added in jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

You could generate the public/private keys on both servers as the jenkins user  to allow password less logins then use the ssh remote actions functionality (can't remember if that is a plug in or default).

Comment: I want this to happen over a given input of SSH credentials when the task is executed. Generating keys would complicate things for my goal...